# Adding dynamic columns to dataframe in R read from a variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to add dynamic columns to dataframe which are comma separated factor.

1) my dataframe

```
Source  Source1  Target   Target.1 Target.2 Target.3
1   SDB1    SDB2     TDB1     TDB2     TDB2     TDB2
2   STB1    STB2     TTB1     TTB2     TTB2     TTB3
3   SCOL1   SCOL2    TCOL1    TCOL2    TCOL3    TCOL4
```

2) Operation

```
df %>%
 slice(1:2) %>%
 t %>%
 as.data.frame() %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 summarise(V2 = toString(unique(V2)))
```

3) it gives me `df2`

```
#    V1         V2
#1 SDB1       STB1
#2 SDB2       STB2
#3 TDB1       TTB1
#4 TDB2 TTB2, TTB3
```

4) I have another dataframe ( any dataframe) with some rows say `iris` dataframe.
5) I want to add value of V2 (TTB2,TTB3) as two added columns to `iris`dataframe. How can I achieve that?

What I tried:

```
df2$V2[1]

[1] TTB2,TTB3

xx <- strsplit(df2$V2[1],", ")
```

which gives

```
 [[1]]
    [1] "TTB2""TTB3"
```

`length(xx [[1]])` is 2

so I can iterate over it but how do I add these dynamic columns?

Comment: Can you check the codes, I get `rror: Must group by variables found in `.data`
* Column `V1` is not found`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate` to split the 'V2' column and then add with the new dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
   select(V2) %>%
   separate(V2, into = c('V2_1', 'V2_2'), sep= ", ", extra = 'merge') %>% 
   bind_cols(head(iris, nrow(df2)), .)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species V2_1  V2_2 
#         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr> <chr>
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  STB1  <NA> 
#2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  STB2  <NA> 
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  TTB1  <NA> 
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  TTB2  TTB3
```

---

In `base R`, we can read the 'V2' column with `read.csv`

```
newdat <- head(iris, nrow(df2))
cbind(newdat, read.csv(text = df2$V2, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   V1    V2
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa STB1      
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa STB2      
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa TTB1      
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa TTB2  TTB3
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:4, .Names = c("Source", "Source1", 
"Target", "Target.1"), .Label = c("SDB1", "SDB2", "TDB1", "TDB2"
), class = "factor"), V2 = c("STB1", "STB2", "TTB1", "TTB2, TTB3"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun , however i was thinking to add TTBA TTB2 etc. as the column names instead of V1,V2 etc.

Comment: @Deep just change it to `separate(V2, into = c('TTBA', 'TTB@')`